# How can we implement failover for aws public api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway, failover

I have seen multiple blogs talking about private API gateway failover in AWS. But how can we implement the same for public API gateway (regional end point)?

I came up with below architecture diagram, Let me know your thoughts to make it better.

[image]

- API Gateway APIs in two AWS Regions
- API Gateway custom domain names with the same name in two AWS Regions
- API Gateway API mappings that connect your API Gateway APIs to the custom domain names
- Route 53 failover DNS records for the domain names. Two CNAME records each pointing to their regional A record.

  - Example: sample.pub.abc.com (cname record) -> sample-us-east-1.pub.abc.com (A record) || sample-us-west-1.pub.abc.com (A record)
- Each A record is pointing to API Gateway domain name